# VBA color fill cell in a range only if cells in another column are not blank

Tags: vba, excel, colors, formatting

I hope you can help. I have a piece of code below. It is called into a bigger piece which I have added further below.

What I want `Public Sub BorderForNonEmpty()`to do is only color fill the blank cells in the range A:C if cells in Column K are not blank. At the moment I have the range set at `Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:C252")` This is only to see if the code would work. It works but it obviously fills in Yellow for all cells that are blank for A2:C252

What I want my code to do is look at Column 11 if there are NO BLANKS cells cell in Column 11 and there are blanks in A:C then yes color. But if there are blank cells in Column 11 just stop looking for blanks to color in A:C and continue on with the rest of the code.

What I want to do is yellow color the blank cells in A, B and C for each country

As always any help is greatly appreciated.

I have added some pics below.

Original pic [image]

Belgium after Macro

[image]

Color blank cells yellow code

```
Public Sub BorderForNonEmpty()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:C252")

    'clear all color
    myRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    'color only blank cells
    myRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End Sub
```

Full Code that opens a dialog box and splits the main workbook into separate workbooks filtered by country in Column 11

FULL CODE

```
Sub Open_Workbook_Dialog()

Dim my_FileName As Variant
Dim my_Workbook As Workbook

  MsgBox "Pick your CRO file" '<--| txt box for prompt to pick a file

  my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*") '<--| Opens the file window to allow selection

  If my_FileName <> False Then
    Set my_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=my_FileName)



    Call Filter(my_Workbook) '<--|Calls the Filter Code and executes

  End If
End Sub

Public Sub Filter(my_Workbook As Workbook)
  Dim rCountry As Range, helpCol As Range
  Dim wb As Workbook
  With my_Workbook.Sheets(1) '<--| refer to data worksheet
    With .UsedRange
      Set helpCol = .Resize(1, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count) '<--| get a "helper" column just at the right of used range, it'll be used to store unique country names in
    End With

   With .Range("A1:Y" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<--| refer to its columns "A:Y" from row 1 to last non empty row of column "A"
            .Columns(11).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=helpCol, Unique:=True '<-- call AdvancedFilter on 11th column of the referenced range and store its unique values in "helper" column
            Set helpCol = Range(helpCol.Offset(1), helpCol.End(xlDown)) '<--| set range with unique names in (skip header row)
            For Each rCountry In helpCol '<--| iterate over unique country names range (skip header row)
                .AutoFilter 11, rCountry.Value2 '<--| filter data on country field (11th column) with current unique country name
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell other than header ones has been filtered...
                    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add '<--... add new Workbook
                        wb.SaveAs Filename:=rCountry.Value2 '<--... saves the workbook after the country
                            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
                               ActiveSheet.Name = rCountry.Value2  '<--... rename it
                           .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'copy data for country under header
                           Sheets(1).Range("A1:Y1").WrapText = False 'Takes the wrap text off
                           ActiveWindow.Zoom = 55
                         Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit 'Autofits the column
                         Call BorderForNonEmpty
                    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True '<--... saves and closes workbook
                End If
            Next
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove autofilter and show all rows back
    End With
    helpCol.Offset(-1).End(xlDown).Clear '<--| clear helper column (header included)
End Sub

Public Sub BorderForNonEmpty()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:C252")

    'clear all color
    myRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    'color only blank cells
    myRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want it to loop through all cells in column K and if there is just 1 blank cell, it should not color anything?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED ***
Try this. It will filter on column K for non-blanks and then add yellow to the blank cells in column A:C.

```
Public Sub Filter
Dim wks As Worksheet

Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

   With wks
     .AutoFilterMode = False
     .Range("A:K").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlFilterValues
     .Range("A:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.Color = 65535
     .AutoFilterMode = False
   End With 
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank your for the help. it is greatly appreciated. Unfortunately I am getting a run time error 1004 on this line `.Range("A:K").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlFilterValues` any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you changed the Sheets("Sheet1") to your sheetname? I believe it should be "Belgium"?

Comment: I need to stay away from naming sheets I need it to be something like my_Workbook.Sheets(1) to get away from errors around sheet names can `Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` be amended so that it does not matter about sheet naming?

Comment: Yes, you can `.Sheets(1)` for the 1st sheet, 2 for the 2nd, etc. Or you can use `.ActiveSheet`. But if you suddenly are in another worksheet than the 1st sheet, it will fail.

Comment: @Nclas: Thank you for the help. I have made the `.Sheets(1)` changes and it is still falling down at `.Range("A:K").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlFilterValues` Is it something to do with the bigger section of code? the part that is going down through Column K then creating workbooks based of country then naming those workbooks and saving?

Comment: Have you tried just to run this procedure? Or have you copied it into your existing code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127559/discussion-between-niclas-and-philip-connell).